# add dynamic class to div using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have more than two  repetitive classes in the pricing-table. I only showed 2 for simplicity.  What am trying to do is to add  class "first"  to the first   `<div class="column dt-sc-one-fourth">`

```
  <div class="dt-sc-pricing-table">
    <div class="column dt-sc-one-fourth">
       <div class="dt-sc-pr-tb-col ">
                    <div class="dt-sc-tb-header">
                        <div class="dt-sc-price"> <sup> $ </sup><sub><span>from</span></sub>95 <span> / month</span> </div>
                        <div class="dt-sc-tb-title"> <h5>Unlimited ADSL</h5> </div>
                        <div class="dt-sc-buy-now">
                            <a class="dt-sc-button medium" href="" nom="residential-unlimited-adsl" taj="Residential">Read More</a></div>
                            </div>
                    <ul class="dt-sc-tb-content">
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
                     </div>
            <div class="column dt-sc-one-fourth">
                <div class="dt-sc-pr-tb-col ">
                    <div class="dt-sc-tb-header">
                        <div class="dt-sc-price"> <sup> $ </sup><sub><span>from</span></sub>99 <span> / month</span> </div>
                        <div class="dt-sc-tb-title"> <h5>Unlimited VDSL</h5> </div>
                        <div class="dt-sc-buy-now">
                            <a class="dt-sc-button medium" href="" nom="residential-unlimited-vdsl" taj="Residential">Read More</a></div>
                            </div>
                    <ul class="dt-sc-tb-content">
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
                     </div>
```

I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dt-sc-one-fourth:first').addClass('first');
    });
    </script>
```

Please help

Comment: Should work fine. any errors in console??

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"  when I place this script after  a custom.js  script file then this error occurs but when I comment the custom.js script out there is no errror but it still does not work

Comment: Do you have other elements (withouth the `column` class) which could have the `dt-sc-one-fourth` class? What happens when you call `$('.first')` in console?

Comment: @Diin: can you share the fiddle.

Comment: @Andreiv  When I call $ ('.first') it gives other  yes there is

Comment: From  your comments I suspect you have some other errors which first need to be solved. As per your question, you state that you want the first element to have both `column`and `dt-sc-one-fourth`. If so, change your code to `$('.column.dt-sc-one-fourth:first').addClass('first');`. Please note that you are actually targeting the first element in the whole page. You might need an additional context in the selector, but this is not clear at the moment.

Comment: Do you want this output? http://jsfiddle.net/Slico/v0ntL4tL/ Take  a look at @AndreiV comment.

Comment: I changed still no luck I am wondering what is causing this.  I have changed $ to jQuery and no error is at console now

Comment: how do i  make it reference  <div class="dt-sc-pricing-table">

Comment: Like this: `$('div .dt-sc-pricing-table')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JQuery is good, if you are only interested in `div`s with that class you can add it to your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div .dt-sc-one-fourth:first').addClass('first');
});
```

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/scwLyoLy/1/

Added css to highlight on class `first`.

```
.first {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

If you still have error, that might be because of something else. Try to separate your code and run it.

**EDIT**

Based on comment: It could help in debugging your problem by including this line in the head of your JS code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before using and JQuery.

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? You want to add class `first` to the first `div` with class `.dt-sc-one-fourth`. That's exactly what happens in the example I gave.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: your code works I have used similar code in other projects but for some reason this is not working in my current project page

Comment: It has to be wrong or missing JQuery reference, or referencing JQuery before defining it.